# how to change the value of a variable in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to use the variables captured in the Debug Sampler in Jmeter and then convert those variables into some other value. And then use it somewhere in the script.

I have added a BeanShell Sampler along with the Debug Sampler and tried to get the variables displayed in the Debug Sampler.
Below is the piece of code I have written in Jmeter.

[Jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meCu0.jpg)

Is my approach correct? Am completely new to Jmeter and have little Java knowledge. So please help me here and let me know how can I convert or use a variable through a Custom code in Jmeter.

Comment: Please add your code directly to the question, formatted as code, not as a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost correct, you have a couple of syntax errors (missing closing bracket and undefined `SomeCharacter`)

Also it is better to use [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) rather than Beanshell, as Groovy performance is much better and it is more Java-compliant, see [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for detailed explanation.

Final code should look something like:

```
def myVariable = vars.get("Corr_ContextN") 

if (myVariable.equals("002056653")) {
    vars.put("myvariable1", "SomeCharacter")
}
```

Keep in mind that you are not changing original `Corr_ContextN`, you are creating new variable `myvariable1`. Also in order to see new variable you need to move the Debug Sampler **after** the Beanshell Sampler

Answer (score 0):

Your got the concept but your code has the following errors:

- imports are wrong and useless. You only need to import Classes for unbound variables, ie the ones that are advertised in the component.
- There's a missing ')' in the if clause
- SomeCharacter is not defined

And you should avoid Beanshell and favor [JSR223 Test Element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) as per those recommandations:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/

Note that there is also a [__groovy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function for your use case.